# program doesnt get the full length of the barcode and as a result i get a response that says "Product not found"

Tags: sql, .net, c#-4.0, barcode-scanner

i am working on a project that scan barcodes and the scan barcode will show in the app so later i can select it and insert the record in a database. As i can see everything works fine despite the fact that the program doesnt get the full length of the barcode and as a result i get a response that says "Product not found".The barcodes im working with are 16 character long (exe.12EM456ME800001P).I have called Ref_No the barcode value. What i have until now is a public sealed class string like this

```
public String(char* value, int startIndex, int length);
```

than i have in another class something like to get the value

```
public string Product_REF_NO
    {
        get { return _Product_REF_NO; }
        set { _Product_REF_NO = value; }
    }
```

and than i have a sql statement with a row like this

```
sqlSelect += " WHERE UPPER(Product_REF_NO) = UPPER('" + Ref_No + "') ";
```

so the program will search in Database for the row with this ref_No and turn it back to my view. But the sql statement Ref_No doest get the full value. If i turn back to the first example of my bar code: if my barcode is this
12EM456ME800001P my Ref_No with get only 12EM456ME800001.

any idea where this comes from? what should i change? where should i retouch my code?
I hope i have explained myself well.